# Is there a way to grab the first field in a Struts form?

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do is give the first field focus, but since the name is generated dynamically I need a way to set the focus attribute to be the first field. Is there a placeholder like form.field[0] or something like that?

Comment: That's more of a JavaScript/HTML question. However, you might try `form.elements[0]` (you'd have to get `form` first, e.g. by some id).

Answer (score 0):

I would set fields styleid and reference it once page is loaded.

JSP:

```
<html:text styleId="tofocus" property="prop" name="<%=dynamic %>" />
```

JavaScript

```
function setFocus()
{ 
    document.getElementById('tofocus').focus();
}

window.onload = setFocus;
```

Comment: I should have been more clear. The entire body of the form is created dynamically. I don't have access to the tags.

Comment: OK, if there is no way you can reference neither field nor form, you can access first input field in the document like that:    `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus()`

Comment: I'm sorry. By body I meant the innards I can still use the form tag. What I ended up doing was this:

 function findAndFocusFirstField() {
  i=0;
  while(document.getElementById("Form1").elements[i].type == "hidden") {
   i++;
  }
  document.getElementById("Form1").elements[i].focus();
 }

Comment: Just notice that you better check your index, for array bounds. You also can use querySelector method with will do the searching for you: `document.getElementById("Form1").querySelector('input:not([hidden]), textarea:not([hidden])').focus()`

Comment: This is a good solution. Sadly `querySelector()` does not work for all the browsers I need.